# Combobox somente leitura

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

Estou tentando fazer com que uma `combobox` fique como apenas leitura (como a opção `ReadOnly` do `textbox`), mexendo nas propriedades do objeto, mas não estou tendo sucesso.

O combobox fica em um windows form comum. Ele será usado para selecionar opções específicas, durante um cadastro de pessoas.
Ao cadastrar, eles funcionarão normalmente. Mas também haverá a opção de pesquisar um cadastro, para não haver duplicatas e o cadastro pesquisado poderá ser aberto para verificar o preenchimento.

Eu gostaria que, ao abrir um cadastro que já foi realizado, os campos que são comboboxes não sejam editáveis como em `comboBox.Enabled=False`, mas que a opção que foi registrada seja selecionável, para poder ser copiada caso necessário, conforme imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Edição**:

Vou dar um exemplo para ficar mais claro.

Eu vou criar o cadastro do Sr. Xisto. Durante a criação do cadastro, a combo sexo (por exemplo) ao ser clicada permite digitar algo ou, se o usuário preferir, pode selecionar a opção na lista que é mostrada ao clicar na seta para baixo. Após preencher todos os campos, o cadastro é finalizado e salvo no banco de dados.

Quando eu procurar pelo cadastro do Sr. Xisto, eu posso abri-lo e verificar os dados que foram digitados. Quando eu verificar a combo sexo, a informação que foi cadastrada será importada do banco de dados.

Se eu clicar nessa combo para aparecer as opções ou tentar escrever algo, não acontecerá nada (como acontece quando ela está desabilitada). Mas a informação que foi importada do banco de dados poderá ser destacada (ficando azul, como na imagem) para poder ser copiada para outro lugar.

**Edição 02**:

Seguindo o raciocínio do @Gabriel, eu estou quase conseguindo deixar como gostaria.

Já está deixando os combos como "somente leitura".

Fiz um projeto separado, para testar e não dar problema e cheguei no código abaixo.

Os combos já estão mudando as cores, não mostrando o `DropDown`, não permitindo digitar, mas permitindo selecionar o que está nela. Só preciso fazer o `ctrl+c` funcionar, quando estão como "somente leitura".

Com todos esses bloqueios que eu coloquei, ainda seria possível habilitar o `ctrl+c`?.

**Edição 03**:

Consegui implementar o `ctrl+c`.Estou colocando abaixo a versão final do código que deixa a `ComboBox` como "somente leitura".

```
    bool consulta;

    void Button1Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (consulta==true)
        {
            consulta = false;
            mudaCorComboEdropDownHeight(Color.White,106);
        }
        else
        {
            consulta = true;
            mudaCorComboEdropDownHeight(Color.WhiteSmoke,1);
        }           
    }
    void MainFormLoad(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
        {
            if (c is ComboBox )
            {
                c.KeyPress += new KeyPressEventHandler(BloqueiaTodosCombobox);
                c.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler (BloqueiaSetasCombobox);
            }
            if (c is GroupBox)
            {
                foreach (Control c2 in c.Controls)
                {
                    if (c2 is ComboBox )
                    {
                        c2.KeyPress += new KeyPressEventHandler(BloqueiaTodosCombobox);
                        c2.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler (BloqueiaSetasCombobox);
                    }
                    if (c2 is TabControl)
                    {
                        foreach (Control c3 in c2.Controls)
                        {
                            if (c3 is TabPage )
                            {
                                foreach (Control c4 in c3.Controls)
                                {
                                    if (c4 is ComboBox )
                                    {
                                        c4.KeyPress += new KeyPressEventHandler(BloqueiaTodosCombobox);
                                        c4.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler (BloqueiaSetasCombobox);
                                    }
                                    if (c4 is GroupBox)
                                    {
                                        foreach (Control c5 in c4.Controls)
                                        {
                                            if (c5 is ComboBox )
                                            {
                                                c5.KeyPress += new KeyPressEventHandler(BloqueiaTodosCombobox);
                                                c5.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler (BloqueiaSetasCombobox);
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            if (c3 is ComboBox )
                            {
                                c3.KeyPress += new KeyPressEventHandler(BloqueiaTodosCombobox);
                                c3.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler (BloqueiaSetasCombobox);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            if (c is TabControl)
            {
                foreach (Control c2 in c.Controls)
                {
                    if (c2 is TabPage )
                    {
                        foreach (Control c3 in c2.Controls)
                        {
                            if (c3 is ComboBox )
                            {
                                c3.KeyPress += new KeyPressEventHandler(BloqueiaTodosCombobox);
                                c3.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler (BloqueiaSetasCombobox);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    if (c2 is ComboBox )
                    {
                        c2.KeyPress += new KeyPressEventHandler(BloqueiaTodosCombobox);
                        c2.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler (BloqueiaSetasCombobox);
                    }
                    if (c2 is GroupBox)
                    {
                        foreach (Control c3 in c2.Controls)
                        {
                            if (c3 is ComboBox )
                            {
                                c3.KeyPress += new KeyPressEventHandler(BloqueiaTodosCombobox);
                                c3.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler (BloqueiaSetasCombobox);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    void BloqueiaTodosCombobox(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if(consulta == true)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
        else
        {
            e.Handled = false;
        }
    }

    void BloqueiaSetasCombobox(object sender, KeyEventArgs f)
    {
        if (!(f.KeyCode==Keys.Left | f.KeyCode==Keys.Right | f.KeyCode==Keys.Home | f.KeyCode==Keys.End | (f.KeyCode == Keys.C && f.Modifiers== Keys.Control)))
        {
            f.Handled=true;
        }
        else
        {
            f.Handled=false;
            if (f.KeyCode == Keys.C && f.Modifiers== Keys.Control)
            {
                Clipboard.SetText(ActiveControl.Text);
            }               
        }
    }
    void bloqueiaDropDown(ComboBox combo, int alturaDropDown)
    {
        combo.DropDownHeight=alturaDropDown;
    }
    void mudaCorComboEdropDownHeight(Color cor, int alturaDropDown)
    {
        foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
        {
            if (c is ComboBox )
            {
                c.BackColor=cor;
                bloqueiaDropDown ((ComboBox)c, alturaDropDown);
            }
            if (c is GroupBox)
            {
                foreach (Control c2 in c.Controls)
                {
                    if (c2 is ComboBox )
                    {
                        c2.BackColor=cor;
                        bloqueiaDropDown ((ComboBox)c2, alturaDropDown);
                    }
                    if (c2 is TabControl)
                    {
                        foreach (Control c3 in c2.Controls)
                        {
                            if (c3 is TabPage )
                            {
                                foreach (Control c4 in c3.Controls)
                                {
                                    if (c4 is ComboBox )
                                    {
                                        c4.BackColor=cor;
                                        bloqueiaDropDown ((ComboBox)c4, alturaDropDown);
                                    }
                                    if (c4 is GroupBox)
                                    {
                                        foreach (Control c5 in c4.Controls)
                                        {
                                            if (c5 is ComboBox )
                                            {
                                                c5.BackColor=cor;
                                                bloqueiaDropDown ((ComboBox)c5, alturaDropDown);
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            if (c3 is ComboBox )
                            {
                                c3.BackColor=cor;
                                bloqueiaDropDown ((ComboBox)c3, alturaDropDown);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            if (c is TabControl)
            {
                foreach (Control c2 in c.Controls)
                {
                    if (c2 is TabPage )
                    {
                        foreach (Control c3 in c2.Controls)
                        {
                            if (c3 is ComboBox )
                            {
                                c3.BackColor=cor;
                                bloqueiaDropDown ((ComboBox)c3, alturaDropDown);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    if (c2 is ComboBox )
                    {
                        c2.BackColor=cor;
                        bloqueiaDropDown ((ComboBox)c2, alturaDropDown);
                    }
                    if (c2 is GroupBox)
                    {
                        foreach (Control c3 in c2.Controls)
                        {
                            if (c3 is ComboBox )
                            {
                                c3.BackColor=cor;
                                bloqueiaDropDown ((ComboBox)c3, alturaDropDown);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**Edição 04**:

Como o código postado é muito específico para o meu caso, vou postar abaixo uma explicação mais genérica para que outras pessoas possam entender melhor e usar.

Assim que o Form é carregado, é executado um laço para atribuir um método em todos os Eventos `KeyPress` e `KeyDown` de todos os `ComboBox`. Caso o `ComboBox` esteja dentro de outro controle, como `GroupBox`, `TabControl e TabPage`ou algum outro, o laço deve ser encadeado.

```
    foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
    {

        if (c is ComboBox )
        {
            //associa o Evento KeyPress da ComboBox localizada com
            // o Método 'BloqueiaTodosCombobox'
            c.KeyPress += new KeyPressEventHandler(BloqueiaTodosCombobox);
            //associa o Evento KeyDown da ComboBox localizada com
            // o Método 'BloqueiaSetasCombobox'
            c.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler (BloqueiaSetasCombobox);
        }
        if (c is GroupBox)
        {
            //Caso o ComboBox  esteja dentro de um GroupBox,
            //fazer o mesmo 'foreach' para buscar o ComboBox
        }
        if (c is TabControl)
        {
            foreach (Control c2 in c.Controls)
            {
                if (c2 is TabPage )
                {
                    //Caso o ComboBox  esteja dentro de um TabPage do TabControl,
                    //fazer o mesmo 'foreach' para buscar o ComboBox.
                    //Basta ir encadeando os foreach para percorrer todos os Controles
                    //necessários, a fim de buscar o ComboBox.
                }
                if (c2 is ComboBox )
                {
                    c2.KeyPress += new KeyPressEventHandler(BloqueiaTodosCombobox);
                    c2.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler (BloqueiaSetasCombobox);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Por causa das travas que foram programadas, para não permitir que seja digitado nada quando estiver como somente leitura, o Ctrl+C deixou de funcionar. Então foi necessário fazê-lo manualmente.

```
        //Caso tenha sido apertado Ctrl+C
        if (f.KeyCode == Keys.C && f.Modifiers== Keys.Control)
        {
            //Manda o conteúdo do Controle ativo (o que está clicado)
            //para o Clipboard, para que possa ser colado com o Ctrl+V
            //em outro lugar que for necessário
            Clipboard.SetText(ActiveControl.Text);
        }
```

Comment: Mas você quer evitar que a pessoa possa escolher qualquer elemento na `comboBox` ? ou evitar que a pessoa escreva opções que não existem ?

Comment: Quando ela estiver como somente leitura eu quero que não possa escrever nada mesmo, apenas selecionar o que foi escolhido na hora do cadastro. Na hora do cadastro não tem problema que escreva algo que não está na combo. Quando eu digo selecionar não quero dizer alterar o conteúdo da combo, quero dizer apenas marcar a palavra como na imagem, pra poder copiar

Comment: Eu ainda não percebi bem o que você está a tentar fazer. Mas `Enabled` indica se o controlo está ativo ou não, que dificilmente é o que quer, uma vez que com `Enabled` a `false` você não pode nem escolher opções sequer. Para tornar as opções não editáveis, forçando o usuário a escolher as que existem, basta apenas trocar o `DropDownStyle` para `DropDownList`

Comment: Eu dei o exemplo do `enabled=false` só para mostrar como eu gostaria que a aparência ficasse. Na imagem que eu anexei mostra como eu quero que fique. A combo da imagem, se você clica nela ou na seta para aparecer as opções, não acontece nada. Se você tenta digitar, também não acontece nada. Mas é possível destacar o texto, como se faz com qualquer texto quando quer usar o `ctrl+c`. O `textbox` tem a propriedade `ReadOnly` que é o exemplo perfeito de como eu quero que a combo fique

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá, se entendi bem você quer tirar a opção de escrever no DropDown mas quer poder selecionar a propiedade text dele.

Essa propiedade deixa readOnly DropDownList = DropDownList, mas não da pra selecionar o texto.

Só isso que sei kkk, sobre copiar o texto não posso ajudar.
Posso sim kkk esqueci disso:

Crie um evento KeyPress no combobox e mude a propiedade Handled pra true dentro do evento; 
e.Handled = true;

```
enum Condicao
    {
        pesquisa, cadastro
    }
    Condicao condicao = Condicao.pesquisa;
    void Muda()
    {
        foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
        {
            if (c is ComboBox)
            {
                c.KeyPress += new KeyPressEventHandler(BloqueiaTodosCombobox);
            }
        }
    }

    void BloqueiaTodosCombobox(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if(condicao == Condicao.pesquisa)
            e.Handled = true;

        else
            e.Handled = false;

    }
```

Comment: O `e.Handled=True`, dentro do evento `KeyPress` serviria apenas para não permitir que seja digitado algo na combo? Eu realmente quero que isso aconteça, mas apenas nesse caso específico de consulta de cadastro. Se eu colocar desta forma, nunca será possível digitar algo (da mesma forma que aconteceria se eu definir a propriedade `DropDownStyle=DropDownList`) ,correto? Nesse caso, eu já não quero que aconteça. Quando o cadastro estiver sendo criado, eu quero que possa ser digitado na combo.

Comment: Sim, tente usar uma condição dentro do evento KeyPress para trocar entre cadastrar e pesquisar ex: if ( ! cadastro) { e.handled = true;} else e.handled = false;

Comment: Partindo do seu raciocínio, eu conseguiria chegar próximo do que eu quero. Pois quando for uma consulta eu uso o evento `KeyPress` para não permitir que seja digitado nada, mudo a cor de fundo para cinza e altero o `DropDownHeight` para 1, para não mostrar a lista de opções, quando for clicado no combobox e quando não for consulta, faço tudo voltar ao normal. Mas eu gostaria de achar uma forma diferente. É uma quantidade considerável de combobox e não ficaria nada prático fazer isso com cada um deles

Comment: o seu código de exemplo me ajudou muito. Eu adicionei na pergunta, o código que eu consegui fazer, partindo do seu exemplo. Ainda falta fazer o `ctrl+c` funcionar, quando estão como "somente leitura". Será que você poderia me auxiliar?

Comment: @Grabriel Consegui implementar o `ctrl+c`. Agradeço novamente pelo código que você postou. Foi de grandíssima ajuda. Editei a pergunta com a versão final do código.

Answer (score 2):

A ComboBox há uma propriedade chamada `DropDownStyle`, nela há um valor onde você escolhe por `DropDownList`, assim, o usuário não poderá digitar na sua caixa de seleção, nem copiar seus valores.

```
this.dropDown1.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
```

### Atualização

Se você quer **travar** a ComboBox, de forma que o usuário não consiga digitar nem alterar seus valores, considere remover todos os itens, exceto o selecionado:

```
public void TravarComboBox(ref ComboBox cb) {
    string data = dropDown1.SelectedText;
    cb.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
    cb.Items.Clear();
    cb.Items.Add(data);
    cb.SelectedIndex = 0;
}
...
TravarComboBox(ref comboBox1);
```

Assim, quando o usuário tentar modificar a ComboBox, não poderá, pois seu campo só terá um valor na lista.

Comment: Desculpa, mas você poderia me esclarecer a sua resposta? Pois a combobox não tem a propriedade `ReadOnly` e para alterar para `DropDownList` é `combobox1.DropDownStyle=ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList`

Comment: @RicardoAlves falta minha, acabei confundindo as bolas. Corrigido, obirgado!